# java heap space error

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to do similar kind of stuff but getting heap space error. What is the solution for this?

```
String mata[][] = new String[100000][100000];    
String matb[][] = new String[100000][100000];   
int j=0;        

for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {        
    if((i%2) == 0){    
        mata[i][j] = "2";
    }else{
        matb[i][j] = "3";   
    }           
    if((i%3) == 2){   
        mata[i][j] = "2";  
    }else{  
        matb[i][j] = "3";  
    }           
 }
```

Comment: You're allocating two arrays that hold up to 10 billion strings each. You might then expect that this would take up a fair bit of memory...[so give it some more.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1565388/3419894)

Comment: there is no practical way you can run a code that wants to create 100k*100k=10 bio String objects. This would require already 80GB (assuming a 64-bit platform) of RAM just for the array. Perhaps you need to store only byte and not strings (back down to 10GB which is still a lot)

Comment: But aren't they variables stocked in the arrays pointing to the String pool? @secolive

Comment: Yes but still 10 bio references, each 8-byte=80GB.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because default heap size is not sufficient to hold 2 x 2d array of size `10000 x 10000`

You can increase the size of heap size using `-Xms64m -Xmx128m`

```
Xms starting heap
Xmx max heap
```

for perm gen space  `-XX:MaxPermSize=128m`

Example `java -Xms64m -Xmx128m -jar MyJar.jar`

Comment: my current heap size is 259522560 (247 MB) , is it not sufficient to hold that data

Comment: what is your RAM size? you can specify less than that if no page file is defined. Do you need this big arrays ?

Answer (score 0):

it will fail with `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`
[Increase heap size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java) to fix this.
You can try something like this

```
java -Xmx6g yourprogram
```